# Is it possible to add dependent text and date field under a checkbox or a dropdown in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to know if I can directly make text and date fileds appear or connect when a  dropdown (or a choice field) or a checkbox (boolean filed) is selected in django models. I know this can be done from the front end with javascript but i don't want to do it from the front end creating input fileds and use javascript to submit data. I have many fileds and if can do it directly from the django admin site then it reduces my burden. I am sharing only the part of the model that I want to act as mentioned above:

**models.py**

```
citation_type = (

    ('SCC', 'SCC'),
    ('AIR', 'AIR'),
    ('AIOL', 'AIOL'),
    ('MLJ', 'MLJ'),
    ('Scale', 'Scale'),
    ('Supreme', 'Supreme'),
    ('A11CJ', 'A11CJ'),
    ('SCC(L&S)', 'SCC(L&S)'),
    ('FLR', 'FLR'),
    ('MhLJ', 'MhLJ')
)
class Laws(models.Model):
        citations = models.Charfield(max_length = 255, choices= citation_type ,null=True)
```

Now here I want that if someone for example chooses 'SCC' from the dropdown then one charfield and datefield related to SCC should appear that stores the data with to SCC. So when I dsiplay it in a html it should look like " citations: SCC (data in charfield)(data in data field) ". If it is not possilble with dropdowns even check boxes will do.

Or suggestions of any other process that does this directly from the models is also aprreciated.

Comment: I don't think we can do this in django because django admin site handle the models and add it to database by query, Admin site don't fetch data it shows that what we created by admin site. As far as I know we can't do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this solely with backend but you can just create all the fields and form in backend then hide/disable necessary fields in the frontend. There is no need to create and submit new fields on the frontend. This will mean you can do all you require in the admin site too.